# configure FosJsRoutingBundle with Symfony4

Tags: symfony4, fosjsroutingbundle

*I would like to use FosJsRoutingBundle with my Symfony4 project.*

---

I already have use this bundle and this integration with symfony is very easy et quickly. But with Symfony4 I have a strange issue for loading all expose route symfony into JavaScript script.

---

**My version of FosJsRoutingBundle** : 
"friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.2",

**I have include my 2 script javascript into head layout page for loading config and routes** :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

**My fos_js_routing.yaml configuration file** :

```
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

**My structure of public folder symfony project** : 
[image]

**And my issue throw when I call my web page** :

Failed on loading for element  which source is

> `http://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData ».`

---

*How can load correctly this bundle with new symfony4 project structure ?*

Answer (score 1):

Have you [published the Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html#step-4-publish-the-assets)?

Symfony 4 isn't described there, but I think you will have to issue

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink public
```

The «web» directory isn't a part of v4.